Create a random numer in Python
how I can create a random number, in Python, according to system date? I write the first and third line below, but I don't know what I must type in second line.
import random

What I must type here for creating a random number according to system date?
print(random.random())


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Seems like the XY problem. Why do you want to do this?

What does "according to system date" mean?  Do you mean that if you run this code many times on the same date, you want it to produce the same random number each time?
